# form in primefaces dialog

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am trying to submit form which is in primefaces dialog `<p:dialog/>`.

```
<h:form>
  <h:inputHidden value="123" id="domesticTransferId" />
  <p:commandButton action="#{domesticTransactionsController.addFirstSignerSignToTransaction}" 
                   id="domesticTransferFirstSignerSign" 
                   value="#{msg['label.FirstSignerSignature']}" 
                   icon="ui-icon-print"  
                   styleClass="myButton" >
  </p:commandButton>
</h:form>
```

It is not calling method that I am expecting to be called.

```
public String addFirstSignerSignToTransaction() {
    try {
        System.out.println("DomesticTransactionsController.addFirstSignerSignToTransaction()");
    } catch(Exception e) {

    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide us with the code of `DomesticTransactionsController`?

Answer (score 1):

Make `p:dialog` `dynamic="true"` and `appendToBody="true"` and try using `process="@form"` on `p:commandButton`.

As mentioned in your comment I guess `domesticTransferId` is a managed property, then you have to use `value` attribute not `id`.

```
 <h:inputHidden value="123" value="#{YOUR_MANAGED_BEAN.domesticTransferId}" />
```

Now it will call the Setter for `domesticTransferId`.

Comment: Thanks it worked but I was expecting that it would call setter method for my hidden input field <h:inputHidden value="123" id="domesticTransferId" />. Setter is public void setDomesticTransferId(Integer domesticTransferId) {
  this.domesticTransferId = domesticTransferId;
 } in my DomesticTransactionsController bean.

Answer (score 1):

Your command button must be :

```
 <p:commandButton action="#{domesticTransactionsController.addFirstSignerSignToTransaction()}" 
               id="domesticTransferFirstSignerSign" 
               value="#{msg['label.FirstSignerSignature']}" 
               icon="ui-icon-print"  
               styleClass="myButton" >
```

You forgot to add () at the end of the method name.

Answer (score -1):

Try with this:

```
public String addFirstSignerSignToTransaction(ActionEvent event){
        System.out.println("DomesticTransactionsController.addFirstSignerSignToTransaction()");

    return "";
}
```

Check that ManagedBean is javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean

Comment: Its an action not actionListener